# Favicon.ico on multi-domain sites?

Tags: magento, dns, favicon

We’re using add-on domains for our multi-site Magento setup running off one skin file on domain1.com and was wondering how we go about setting up a favicon for each store?

We will have a total of 10 domains by the time we finish setting up this project so obviously want 10 different favicon’s.

I’ve tried this - http://vanesz.awardspace.info/magento_favicon_tweak/

Which works in some respect and show’s the relevant icon on things like google webmaster tools but it doesn’t work as a bookmark icon and as an icon at the top of the page on browsers like chrome.

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a post about that:

- http://drupal.org/node/17704

Basically, you do this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

and change href to whatever you want.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, was trying to make a simple thing overcomplicated!